# Elliptic Curve - How to handle division at point multiplication

Tags: c++, integer, division, multiplication, elliptic-curve

I am working on implementing EC-calculations (first) in C++. Everything makes sense to me, but the division used in point multiplication. As I understand using integers is common but the division of lambda (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication) for addition or doubling a point gives some uncertainty because of the approximation of the result. How is this normally handled, so everyone gets the same results despite using different amount of numbers after dot?

(Unfortunately I could not find the implementation of the return of the EC_POINT_add function by openssl to compare their solution)

Answer (score 2):

I made a tiny Python library that does all Elliptic Point operations, including multiplication and addition.

Also made similar C++ library with same code but re-written in C++.

Although you tagged question with C++, still your question is more generic, mathematical, hence I decided to share two Python function below, only to explain you answer to your question on real example. Think of Python just as more understandable (than C++) pseudocode:

```py
def __add__(self, other):
    A, B, N = self.A, self.B, self.N
    Px, Py, Qx, Qy = self.x, self.y, other.x, other.y
    if Px == Qx and Py == Qy:
        s = ((Px * Px * 3 + A) * pow(Py * 2, -1, N)) % N
    else:
        s = ((Py - Qy) * pow(Px - Qx, -1, N)) % N
    x = (s * s - Px - Qx) % N
    y = (s * (Px - x) - Py) % N
    return ECPoint(A, B, N, x, y)

def __rmul__(self, other):
    assert other >= 1
    if other == 1:
        return self
    other -= 1
    r = self
    while True:
        if other & 1:
            r = r + self
            if other == 1:
                return r
        other >>= 1
        self = self + self
```

Here in point addition you can see that I used construct as `pow(a, -1, n)`, it is finding [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `a` modulo `n`.

This is exactly what you called division. As you probably know you can find modular inverse through [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

As you should know from math of [Elliptic Curve Point Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication), there are two places where we have division, I pointed these places with arrow on picture below:

[image: img]

This division is basically modular inversion of a number. For example in picture above in denominator we have `... / (Xq - Xp)`. It means just that we seek for such `A` that `A * (Xq - Xp) = 1 (mod N)`, this `A` is called modular inverse of `Xq - Xp` modulus `N` (this is modulus taken from Elliptic Curve Equation). In python we'll just write `A = pow(Xq - Xp, -1, N)` - this function computes modular inverse.

So we don't do actually any actual division, in a sense of floating point arithmetic, here is a division is only in modular sense.

If you have any questions, for example if you need more formulas, or more explanation, or more code, then please tell in comments. Also, if you need full code either in Python or C++, full code of Elliptic Curve computations, then also tell me.

Comment: So your answer is "Extended Euclidean Algorithm"

Answer (score 2):

In the scope of "implementing EC-calculations" you might basically consider point operations in projective coordinates, (X,Y) <--> (XZ,YZ,Z). This avoids continuous *expensive* inversions in point multiplication.

See [Project Nayuki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/elliptic-curve-point-addition-in-projective-coordinates). The link also references Python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be modular division or better multiplication of the inverse element.